# How is an interface explicitly called from XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following property in my view model:

```
private ICheckin _editor;
        public ICheckin Editor
        {
            get { return _editor; }
            set { _editor = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

The Editor explicitly implements many interfaces:

```
Editor : ICheckin, IBilling, IInsurance, IAccount, IPaidOnAccount, IReportManager
```

How do I explicitly specify one of these interfaces in the view / xaml?

i.e., *something* like:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding (IReportManager)Editor.firstencounter}" ....
```

where firstencounter is a property  of the Editor explicitly specified by the IReportManager interface.

Does WPF Binding support this? If so how, if not what is normally done for this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your interfaces do not have common method you can call directly your property.
like {Binding Editor.xyz}.

Or you can use converter and pass parameters that return desired property value from interface.
Like this.

```
 Text="{Binding Editor, Converter={StaticResource InterfaceConverter}, ConverterParameter=IReportManager}"
```